# Why does my minecraft crash every time I join?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm running a minecraft server for 3 friends. It has been working fine for a week, but now crashed almost instantly when I join. Below is the low, but I dont really know what Im looking for or how to fix it. I have no mods installed.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Daisy, daisy...

Time: 1/12/16 10:22 PM
Description: Watching Server

java.lang.Error
    at adm.a(SourceFile:204)
    at adm.a(SourceFile:217)
    at adm.e(SourceFile:213)
    at adm.b(SourceFile:604)
    at adm.a(SourceFile:2083)
    at adm.c(SourceFile:2106)
    at adm.x(SourceFile:2053)
    at amy.e(SourceFile:1161)
    at amy.n(SourceFile:1094)
    at amy.b(SourceFile:916)
    at le.h(SourceFile:332)
    at le.c(SourceFile:202)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.B(SourceFile:599)
    at ko.B(SourceFile:299)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.A(SourceFile:535)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:451)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at adm.a(SourceFile:204)
    at adm.a(SourceFile:217)
    at adm.e(SourceFile:213)
    at adm.b(SourceFile:604)
    at adm.a(SourceFile:2083)
    at adm.c(SourceFile:2106)
    at adm.x(SourceFile:2053)
    at amy.e(SourceFile:1161)
    at amy.n(SourceFile:1094)
    at amy.b(SourceFile:916)
    at le.h(SourceFile:332)
    at le.c(SourceFile:202)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.B(SourceFile:599)
    at ko.B(SourceFile:299)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.A(SourceFile:535)

-- Thread Dump --
Details:
    Threads: "Netty Server IO #2" Id=33 RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(Unknown Source)
    -  locked io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet@7ecb2fee
    -  locked java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet@700cce47
    -  locked sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@7433449e
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:622)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:310)
    ...


"File IO Thread" Id=50 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at auc.c(SourceFile:51)
    at auc.run(SourceFile:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


"Netty Server IO #1" Id=32 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(Unknown Source)
    -  locked io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet@3131c47c
    -  locked java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet@162229eb
    -  locked sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@4ab39e
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:622)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:310)
    ...


"Server Watchdog" Id=48 RUNNABLE
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method)
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(Unknown Source)
    at kp.run(SourceFile:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


"Netty Server IO #0" Id=31 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(Unknown Source)
    -  locked io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet@6eb300bd
    -  locked java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet@511e3b33
    -  locked sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@56f43d8a
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:622)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:310)
    ...


"DestroyJavaVM" Id=29 RUNNABLE


"Server console handler" Id=28 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    -  locked java.io.BufferedInputStream@3f7a289
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    -  locked java.io.InputStreamReader@75b7eca2
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    ...


"Server thread" Id=26 RUNNABLE
    at adm.a(SourceFile:204)
    at adm.a(SourceFile:217)
    at adm.e(SourceFile:213)
    at adm.b(SourceFile:604)
    at adm.a(SourceFile:2083)
    at adm.c(SourceFile:2106)
    at adm.x(SourceFile:2053)
    at amy.e(SourceFile:1161)
    ...


"AWT-EventQueue-0" Id=23 RUNNABLE
    at sun.font.T2KFontScaler.getGlyphMetricsNative(Native Method)
    at sun.font.T2KFontScaler.getGlyphMetrics(Unknown Source)
    -  locked sun.font.T2KFontScaler@55508684
    at sun.font.FileFont.getGlyphMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at sun.font.FileFontStrike.getGlyphMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at sun.font.FileFontStrike.getGlyphAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.font.FileFontStrike.getGlyphImageFromWindows(Unknown Source)
    at sun.font.FileFontStrike.getGlyphImageFromNative(Unknown Source)
    at sun.font.FileFontStrike.getGlyphImagePtr(Unknown Source)
    ...


"AWT-Shutdown" Id=24 WAITING on java.lang.Object@22bff9c9
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.Object@22bff9c9
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


"TimerQueue" Id=22 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@567ad92f
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@567ad92f
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Number of locked synchronizers = 1
    - java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@1c62e4fd


"Thread-4" Id=21 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@7cf11c2
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@7cf11c2
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at com.mojang.util.QueueLogAppender.getNextLogEvent(QueueLogAppender.java:77)
    at kr$4.run(SourceFile:114)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


"AWT-Windows" Id=17 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


"Java2D Disposer" Id=15 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@5ae3c143
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@5ae3c143
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


"Server Infinisleeper" Id=14 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at ko$1.run(SourceFile:65)


"Snooper Timer" Id=13 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.TaskQueue@512d93ee
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.TaskQueue@512d93ee
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)


"Attach Listener" Id=5 RUNNABLE


"Signal Dispatcher" Id=4 RUNNABLE


"Finalizer" Id=3 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@511e8b45
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@511e8b45
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)


"Reference Handler" Id=2 WAITING on java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@2ea0d1a5
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@2ea0d1a5
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)



Stacktrace:
    at kp.run(SourceFile:59)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8.9
    Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2 (amd64) version 6.3
    Java Version: 1.8.0_65, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 1214620224 bytes (1158 MB) / 1401946112 bytes (1337 MB) up to 1908932608 bytes (1820 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M
    IntCache: cache: 1, tcache: 1, allocated: 12, tallocated: 94
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Player Count: 1 / 20; [lf['negativesixtysix'/282, l='world', x=-61.52, y=81.00, z=-877.51]]
    Is Modded: Unknown (can't tell)
    Type: Dedicated Server (map_server.txt)
```

Comment: No mods at all?  No bukkit, no forge, no nothing?  The crash log can't tell if it's modded or not; that usually means you've done something to it.

Comment: @Frank it mentions server.

Comment: From what I've found, "Watching Server" crashes are related to [MC-63590](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-63590), which is as intended. I'll work on an answer shortly.

Comment: I have the strong suspicion that this is a hacked client. The log contains phrases I have never seen before, such as thread names, and "Is Modded: Unknown (can't tell)" indicates tampered files as well.

Comment: @MrLemon This is not a hacked client.

Comment: @MrLemon This is a server crash log.

Comment: @user230250 fair enough. I still recommend re-downloading the server software, as there is *definitely* something wrong with the file.

Answer (score 1):

This crash was caused by a feature called the server watchdog, which was added in 1.8. Its job is to shut the server down if a single server tick takes more than a configurable number of milliseconds (by default 60000, or 60 seconds).

You can work around this by setting `max-tick-time` in `server.properties` to a higher number, or to `-1`, to disable it entirely. See [MC-63590](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-63590) for more details.

Comment: That said, the fact that server watchdog needs to do anything is probably indicative of a larger problem. More ram might be a possible avenue to follow, but it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that for me. I will double the ram allowed and see if that fixes the issue!